# Spring Cloud Stream Reactive, how to set routing key for producer

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

Spring Cloud Stream allows us to set routing key using application config, like:

```
cloud.stream:
    default:
      contentType: "application/json"

    rabbit.bindings:
      output-resync-events:
        producer:
          prefix: "xxx."
          routing-key-expression: '''command.service'''

    bindings:
      output-resync-events:
        destination: "resync-requests"
```

But I need to set the `routing-key` dynamically for each message send.

I know about `BinderAwareChannelResolver` but it seems this only allows you to create a new `Exchange` itself which is not the desired outcome.

I want to use the same `TopicExchange` but with different `routing-key`s.

Also if it is possible to achieve this using the Spring Cloud Stream's Reactive APIs?

Comment: I think you're looking for `routingKeyExpression`, which would essentially allow you to use say message header.- https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Fishtown.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbit_producer_properties

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky correct me if I am wrong, but `routingKeyExpression` can only be set in the application.properties file or the application.yaml file. But I want to programmatically decide the `routing key` which may be different for each and every message I send, but I always want to publish to the same TopicExchange

Comment: The `routingKeyExpression` is going to be execute programmatically upon each message to determine the routing key. So executing expression on the `Message` (e.g., message headers) will allow you to be as dynamic as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses a SPEL so you can set it at run time like this:

`messagingConfig.dataCopiedChannel().send(MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader("type", "key-stuff").build());`

where messagingConfig is your interface for bindings being injected into a class to send out the message.

You then configure your application.properties to look like this

`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.data-copied.destination=data.topic.exchange
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.data-copied.producer.routing-key-expression=headers.type`

This would send it to the data.topic.exchange with a routing key of "key-stuff".